# Converting MySQL query to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
SELECT * FROM test.pchi new INNER JOIN rlhi old ON new_id = old.menu_id where new.name='?'
```

Similar to:

```
Select * from db.employee emp INNER JOIN db.table on emp_tableID = table.id where emp.name = '?'
```

If you could tell me how to do a projection, that would be awesome... as in:

```
Select emp.name, emp.sex, table.brand from ....
```

I tried using fetch, but I'm very new to this and keep getting some weird errors. Could someone please demonstrate how to do this?

How about this?

```
sess.createCriteria(pchi.class)/**/
              .setFetchMode("rlhi", FetchMode.JOIN)
              .add(Restrictions.eq("new_id", "rlhi.menu_id"))
              .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "SOME INPUT"))
```

Comment: No No. new_id from pchi and old_id from rlhi.

Comment: cause you change :D better now

Comment: lol... yeah. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sess.createCriteria(Pchi.class)
              .setFetchMode("rlhi", FetchMode.JOIN) //note that rlh1 is the property name in Pchi class
              .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "SOME INPUT"));
```

In your class you have something like this

```
class Pchi{
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="new_id", referencedColumnName="menu_id")
private Rlhi rlhi;
}

class Rlhi{
@OneToMany(mappedBy="rlhi")
private <Set> Pchi pchis;
}
```

**NOTE** When you use `SET` should override `equals()` and `hashCode()` method to work properly

Comment: Hey thanks!

Well, but will this do the join on the two columns I have specified above?

Comment: @gran_profaci i edited, just try i cant try here so may be has errors, watch in the output how many queries executed cause u have to avoid n+1 select

Comment: Thank you very much!! Let me try this!