# Converting SQL query into an equivalent Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, i have written few queries in MYSQL but i need to convert those queries into hibernate criteria.

**SQL Query**

```
select * from tableName where type = 'some Loss' and (datediff(detection_time,clearing_time )> '15 minutes' or action = 'ACTIVE') and id = '216';
```

I have tried few codes using criteria but it doesn't seem working.

Comment: does this have anything to do with SQL-Server? if not remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATEDIFF` correctly and specify a unit, i.e. `MINUTE`.

See [Documentation - DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx)

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.
>
> **Syntax**: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   [type] = 'some Loss'
        AND ( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, detection_time, clearing_time) > 15
              OR action = 'ACTIVE'
            )
        AND id = '216';
```

Comment: looks like it's MySQL function is used (2 arguments). Guess the *sql-server* is wrong tag

Comment: @StanislavL sql-server was tagged, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before. Only difference is that the question was about MySQL instead of plain SQL. But I think you should be able to easily transfer it.

Maybe this helps:

[Converting MySQL query to Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055874/converting-mysql-query-to-hibernate-criteria)

UPDATE:

I just saw there are two more answered question which could help:

[Converting mysql query into hibernate query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689840/converting-mysql-query-into-hibernate-query)

[How to write hibernate criteria for this sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625811/how-to-write-hibernate-criteria-for-this-sql-query)